# why return list_name.append(something) returns none?

Tags: python, function, parameters, mutable

when I define function f which append a value to a list
in this structure :

```
     list_name=[]
     return list_name.append(a)
```

```
>>>print(f(1))
none
```

---

and when i define it in the following structure:

```
def f (a) :
     list_name=[]
     list_name.append(a)
     return list_name
```

it gives the right output

```
>>>print(f(1))
[1]
>>>print(f(2))
[2]
```

what is the difference between `return list_name.append(a)` and

```
list_name.append(a)
return list_name
```

??

Comment: The second one is returning an action. The return statement is used to exit the function and give you something as it exits.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the `append` function is `None`, which is a Pythonic way of saying that it does not return a value.

Basically, the `append` function does not return a value, rather performs an operation (adding elements to the of the list), and that's it.

You are trying to return the result of a function which does not return a value, and hence, the output is `None`.

On the other hand, when you try the second way, the `append` operation has already taken place, and you return an object of type `<List>`, which works without any problem.

Comment: thanks for help ...<3

Answer (score 0):

`list_name.append(a)` doesn't explicitly return anything, it just changes the list. It's sort of like how print doesn't return anything, it just prints what you gave it onto the screen. This is a common pattern where when a method like append which just modifies an object or has some effect doesn't return anything. But in Python, you can't not return anything, so the default is to just return None. In fact, both `list_name.append(a)` and `print('hello')` really do return `None`, even though the definitions of those methods/functions might not explicitly say `return None` at the end. For example, try running this code:

```py
def do_something():
    a = 1

x = do_something()
print(x)
```

The value of `x` is `None` despite us not writing `return None` at the end of `do_something`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just thought it would be helpful for op to think of that default returning `None` behavior as the result of not explicitly returning anything in a function. I'll update my wording to be more clear

Comment: many thanks ... <3